# Get even/odd indices of a matrix - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, indices

I have following problem:

I have a given matrix of let's say `4x4`.
How can I get the indices of the following combinations:

- row odd and column odd
- row odd and column even
- row even and column odd
- row even and column even

For example if I have the matrix:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

- 'row odd and column odd' would be the indices of 1, 3, 9, 11...
- 'row odd and column even' would be the indices of 2, 4, 10, 12...
- 'row even and column odd' would be the indices of 5, 7, 13, 15...
- and 'row even and column even' would be indices of 6, 8, 14, 16...

Also, is it possible to combine those operations so e.g. I get the indices for 'row odd and column odd' and 'row even and column even'?

Thank you!

Comment: If your matrix is called `A` then you can get odd rows and even columns like this: `A(1:2:end, 2:2:end)`. From there the rest should be easy (basically just a matter of starting at `1` for odd and at `2` for even

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's pretty easy to do with indexing:

## Odd rows and odd columns

```
B = A(1:2:end, 1:2:end);
```

## Odd rows and even columns

```
B = A(1:2:end, 2:2:end);
```

## Even rows and odd columns

```
B = A(2:2:end, 1:2:end);
```

## Even rows and even columns

```
B = A(2:2:end, 2:2:end);
```

---

The above assumes that you want the actual matrix values themselves.  It's a bit confusing as your matrix elements are the same as linear indexing values themselves.  If you want to determine the actual column major indices to access the matrix, you can generate a vector from `1 to N` where `N` is the total number of elements in your matrix, then reshape this matrix into the desired size that you want.  After, use the same logic above to get the actual linear indices:

```
N = numel(A);
B = reshape(1:N, size(A,1), size(A,2));
ind = B(1:2:end, 1:2:end); %// For odd rows, odd columns
%// Repeat for the other ones...
```

Now, given your comment, you want to create a new matrix that will store only these extracted matrix values while making all of the other elements zero.  If you want to do this, simply pre-allocate a matrix of zeroes, then copy over those values to extract using the computed indices into the new matrix.  In other words:

```
N = numel(A);
B = reshape(1:N, size(A,1), size(A,2));
ind = B(1:2:end, 1:2:end); %// For odd rows, odd columns - Change to suit your tastes
out = zeros(size(A));
out(ind(:)) = A(ind(:));
```

---

If you want to combine the indices like having odd row - odd column, and even row - even column, just compute two sets of indices, concatenate them into a single vector and do the same syntax like before.  Therefore:

```
N = numel(A);
B = reshape(1:N, size(A,1), size(A,2));
ind = B(1:2:end, 1:2:end); %// For odd rows, odd columns
ind2 = B(2:2:end, 2:2:end); %// For even rows, even columns
ind = [ind(:); ind2(:)];
out = zeros(size(A));
out(ind) = A(ind);
```

Comment: Actually I want to do the following:

given a matrix I want to extract those values, depending on even/odd rows/cols into another matrix of the same!! size and fill all indices that were not copied with zeros. For example if I have the matrix

(1 2,
3 4)

and I want the odd/odd and even/even the new matrix will be filled with 

(0 2,
3 0)

I hope thats a better explanation

Comment: @DrSkyer Do `new_matrix(ind(:)) = A(ind(:))` after pre-allocating for new_matrix. BTW +1, I messed it up initially :)

Comment: @Divakar - Thanks for the +1 :) I will admit that I was a bit perplexed to see you using `bsxfun` lol.

Comment: @DrSkyer I have made a similar edit, if you would like to check it out too :)

Comment: @rayryeng I like your solution, but comeon one-liners are the way to go ;) Actually jokes aside, with no use of about 75% of `B`, it's sort of waste isn't it? :)

Comment: @Divakar - Well... that is true yes.  One alternative I could recommend is to use `sub2ind`, and define a `ndgrid` of co-ordinates that conforms to what the OP wants.  That way, you're not wasting (as much) space.

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

```
N = size(A,1); %// Get size of input matrix A

case1_ind = bsxfun(@plus,[1:2:N]',(0:N/2-1)*2*N)
case2_ind = case1_ind + N
case3_ind = case1_ind + 1
case4_ind = case3_ind + N
```

Note: These outputs are indices. So, to get the actual outputs, use these as indices.

To combine indices for `case 1` and `case 4`, just concatenate -

```
case14comb_ind = [case1_ind ; case4_ind]
```

**Edit :**

```
%// To copy onto some other matrix of the same size as A, do this for case 1
new_matrix = zeros(size(A))
new_matrix(case1_ind(:)) = A(case1_ind(:))
```

Repeat this for the other cases too.

Comment: I would like to upvote both your answers but I don't have the 15 reputation for that xD sorry!

Thank you anyways!

Comment: @DrSkyer Comeon don't lie! ;) Just kidding, you can do now :)

Comment: @Divakar - Fine I will upvote your answer :P.  I wanted to anyway, but I forgot!